# Find products that have a list of attributes

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck trying to solve a problem that's proving to be more difficult than it seems.

Consider there is a table that associates products with attributes, it looks like this:

```
Products_id | Attribute_id
    21      |      456
    21      |      231
    21      |      26
    22      |      456
    22      |      26
    22      |      116
    23      |      116
    23      |      231
```

Next, I have a list of attribute_ids which I want to use in order to get the products that have all the attributes in that list.

For example if I search in the table above using this list (456, 26) I should get these product_ids 21 and 22.
Another example, if I search for (116, 231) I should get 23 since the product 23 is the only on that has both these attributes.

How can I achieve this using one query?

I hope I made my question clear.

Thanks.

Comment: >  if I search for (116, 231) I should get an empty response
Maybe 23, not an empty response?

Answer (score 3):

If you hand-craft your query:

```
SELECT Products_ID
  FROM ProductAttributes
 WHERE Attribute_ID IN (116, 231)
 GROUP BY Products_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This asks for all the products where the number of entries with the given attributes is equal to the number of attributes.  If you want to generalize, you do a join against a table of the interesting product attribute ID values.

Answer (score 1):

```
select product_id from products 
where attribute_id in (123,234) 
group by product_id having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: You want to distinct the table first, if your precondition isn't that it's distinct.

Comment: @tpdi: why?  Grouping does that - and it is reasonable to assume that the table has unique rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select products_id from table where attribute_id = 456
intersect
select products_id from table where attribute_id = 26;
```

Comment: "intersect" wasn't recognized by my mySQL (version 5.1.33).